# Animate map region in react-native-maps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

In the simplest way possible how would I animate the region of the map so that the marker I have just clicked on is positioned at the centre of the screen, and also in other cases at the centre of the the top half of the screen (between quarter 1 and 2)?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use Animated.Region in your state, for example :

```
 region: new Animated.Region({
        latitude:       lat,
        longitude:      lng,
        latitudeDelta:  0.01,
        longitudeDelta: 0.01,
 })
```

Then, after the marker is selected (onSelect / onPress) you can take its location and animate the region to it :

```
var {region} = this.state;
region.timing({
    latitude:  newLat, // selected marker lat
    longitude: newLong, // selected marker lng
  }).start();
```

In the render method, remember to use MapView.Animated and connect it with the animated region.

Comment: Thats great thanks, but if I am not mistaken that will align that location to the centre of the screen right? If I wanted to navigate to that location but make it the centre of the top half of the screen (rather than the actual centre), is it possible to do? Reason is there is a bottom sheet covering the bottom half of the map, hence the need for the top half centring of the marker